# Update a column of a table with append some values to the same column value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Lock issue occurred when i tried to update a Column of a table with concatenate the same column value with some characters.

```
UPDATE Templates 
   SET TemplateName = CONCAT("'", (SELECT TemplateName 
                                           FROM Templates 
                                          WHERE LogID = 2), '_Validated',"'")
 WHERE LogID = 2;
```

Is there any possible ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
UPDATE TEMPLATES
   SET TemplateName = CONCAT("'", templatename, '_Validated')
 WHERE LogID = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply..Sorry i have mistaken the code.. both are the same tables.. kindly saw the updated code :)