# Update Email in Mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have lots of entries in my table **USERS**. Its contains up to 500 email.

Example:

```
rskidmore@soundviewprep.org
53e935da@mail.com
james.vh@naturescomfortllc.com
arlie@lottapop.com
gigabite10@att.net
```

I want to updated all email with "1" postfix.
Output should be

```
rskidmore@soundviewprep1.org
53e935da@mail1.com
james.vh@naturescomfortllc1.com
arlie@lottapop1.com
gigabite10@att1.net
```

Is this possible with single query with replacing last occurrence of "." ???

Comment: I don't think it can be done with a query alone. You may need to use PHP to put the `1` in the right place

Comment: May be it can done by replacing last occurrence of "."

Comment: @Manwal no possible. what if the id is abc@def.ac.uk

Comment: @paradox its very much possible try this `select 
replace('rskidmore@soundviewprep.co.uk.id',
       substring_index(substring_index('rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep.co.uk.id','@',-1),'.',1),
       concat(substring_index(substring_index('rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep.co.uk.id','@',-1),'.',1),'1')
       
) as result ;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes this could be done as

```
select 
replace('james.vh@naturescomfortllc.com',
       substring_index(substring_index('james.vh@naturescomfortllc.com','@',-1),'.',1),
       concat(substring_index(substring_index('james.vh@naturescomfortllc.com','@',-1),'.',1),'1')
)
```

Here are few tests

```
mysql> select 
    -> replace('james.vh@naturescomfortllc.com',
    ->        substring_index(substring_index('james.vh@naturescomfortllc.com','@',-1),'.',1),
    ->        concat(substring_index(substring_index('james.vh@naturescomfortllc.com','@',-1),'.',1),'1')
    -> ) as result ;
+---------------------------------+
| result                          |
+---------------------------------+
| james.vh@naturescomfortllc1.com |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select 
    -> replace('rskidmore@soundviewprep.org',
    ->        substring_index(substring_index('rskidmore@soundviewprep.org','@',-1),'.',1),
    ->        concat(substring_index(substring_index('rskidmore@soundviewprep.org','@',-1),'.',1),'1')
    ->        
    -> ) as result ;
+------------------------------+
| result                       |
+------------------------------+
| rskidmore@soundviewprep1.org |
+------------------------------+


mysql> select 
    -> replace('rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep.co.uk',
    ->        substring_index(substring_index('rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep.co.uk','@',-1),'.',1),
    ->        concat(substring_index(substring_index('rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep.co.uk','@',-1),'.',1),'1')
    ->        
    -> ) as result ;
+----------------------------------+
| result                           |
+----------------------------------+
| rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep1.co.uk |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So here is the update command

```
update your_table set email = 
replace(
 email,
 substring_index(substring_index(email,'@',-1),'.',1),
 concat(substring_index(substring_index(email,'@',-1),'.',1),'1')
) ;
```

Comment: I have tested this update command its giving "test1@test1.com" for "test@test.com". Fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ed6bc/1. why it so?

Comment: Hmm I know, its trying to replace the word test with test1 so once you have test@test.com both are getting replaced, which is very unlikely to happen for a real email id, you may never see an email id as `yahoo@yahoo.com`,`gmail@gmail.com`

Comment: @Manwal: Why is this the best answer? Its wrong. A "xyz@a.b.c.company.net" will be set to "xyz@a1.b.c.compa1ny.net" by this statement.

Comment: @hellcode I looked more into it and there is no end if you try your solution with `xyz@a1.b.c.compa1ny.co.net` , it fails. My solution will fail for the one you specified. In fact it fails for any email id @co.uk or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
UPDATE `USERS` SET `email` = CONCAT( SUBSTRING(`email`, 1, LENGTH(`email`) -1 -LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`email`, '.', -1))), '1.', SUBSTRING_INDEX(`email`, '.', -1));
```

If you have to consider that "co.uk" must be an unbreakable unit, you could use this (and may add more of such subdomain constellations if you want):

```
UPDATE `USERS` SET `email` = IF(
SUBSTRING(`email`,-6)=".co.uk"
, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`email`,1,LENGTH(`email`)-6), "1.co.uk")
, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(`email`,1,LENGTH(`email`)-1-LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`email`, '.', -1))), '1.', SUBSTRING_INDEX(`email`, '.', -1))
);
```

Comment: Try this  `select CONCAT( SUBSTRING('rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep.co.uk', 1, LENGTH('rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep.co.uk') -1 -LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX('rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep.co.uk', '.', -1))), '1.', SUBSTRING_INDEX('rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep.co.uk', '.', -1)) as res ;`

Comment: @Manwal if you take `rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep.co.uk` as your email the above will give you `rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep.co1.uk` and you have no control on email ids it could be anything.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: yours is working for xyz@something.co.uk but not for xyz@a.b.c.company.net

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple Using `CONCAT()` , `LENGTH()` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`. I have tested below query

```
UPDATE 
  your_table 
SET
  email = CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '.', 1),
    '1.',
    IF(
      (
        LENGTH(email) - LENGTH(REPLACE(email, '.', ''))
      ) = 2,
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '.', - 2),
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '.', - 1)
    )
  ) ;
```

You can refer [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html), The above mysql functions

This solution even works good with

```
test@test.com             test@test1.com
test@yahoo.in             test@yahoo1.in
test@happy.co.in          test@happy1.co.in
```

Comment: This will fail for `select CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep.co.uk', '.', 1),'1.',SUBSTRING_INDEX('rskid.mo.re@soundviewprep.co.uk', '.', -1)) as res ;`

Comment: Yes correct @AbhikChakraborty. its not working for james.vh@naturescomfortllc1.com.

Comment: yes try to match with @ since an email can have one @ and then do the replacement.

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty How is my solution?

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use a scripting language which could easily do this, splitting the string, adding '1' and then joining them back. I dunno if its possible only with SQL. This is the append in sql. [SQL query to prepend prefix to existing value in a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358923/sql-query-to-append-prefix-to-existing-value-in-a-field) Also you can use the `LIKE` construct for a regex to identify the links . Also [Update a column of a table with append some values to the same column value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857746/update-a-column-of-a-table-with-append-some-values-to-the-same-column-value-in-m). I think you will have to use these to create a work-around

Comment: This is not i want. :(